# Is it safe to upgrade XCode 4.6.3 to Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed a Universal App that works on both an iPad running iOS 9.3.5 & an iPhone running iOS 6.1.4, using two different Storyboards.

I realise that I need to upgrade in order to be able to distribute my App on the App Store.

Can I run Xcode 7 on OS X Lion? And, more importantly, will my Objective-C code still work in Xcode 7?

The code I am using is very basic. I am essentially using a UINavigationController to present data from an SQLite database.
I am not using any animation, location services or camera based classes.
At the moment, I have set my deployment target as 6.1.
I am using 2 third party frameworks: SSZipArchive & Reachability

Can anyone give me some reassurance, before I assign a month's worth of work to the scrap heap?

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to tell, since it means jumping 3 versions (!) ahead.
 Anyway, I wholeheartedly recommend you to set git in your project, to make sure you can always revert if something goes wrong.
 BTW- I would recommend updating to Xcode 8, the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Git. I never actually realised I could store iOS projects on GitHub. I actually have a BitBucket account, which I use for my Coldfusion projects, so I will try create a repository there.

Comment: I have just pushed my project to BitBucket. Hopefully, this will safeguard my files, if things go tits up;)

Answer (score 1):

Following are the answers to your queries :

1. Which version of Xcode 7, you will be using? You will have to upgrade your OS too to run Xcode 7 as it runs on OS X 10.10.4
2. Your code will probably work on Xcode 7, but you might have to tweak a few things. But you will have a lot of online help to fix these issues.

Comment: I didn't realise we are now on XCode 8, so I will be updating to this, rather than XCode 7. shallowThought has alerted me to the fact that my Storyboard might cause a few issues. Let the fireworks begin;)

Comment: Yeah, be ready for them. When we shifted from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8, there were lots of fireworks :P

Comment: Well. I might as well deal with all the problems, in one go, although I guess the headache will continue ad infinitum when Apple release XCode 9, and iOS 11. It never ends. The life of a developer, hey...;)

Answer (score 1):

From Xcode 7s Release notes:

> Xcode 7 requires a Mac running OS X 10.10.4

In general, you can copy `/Applications/Xcode.app` to `/Applications/Xcode_4_6_3.app` and than update (or maybe better install) `Xcode 8`beside it, so you can always use your legacy version side-by-side.

Without knowing your code nobody can tell if it needs modifications to build under `Xcode7`. As the step from `Xcode 4` to `Xcode 7` is big, plus you want to build for the App Store and therefor have to target iOS 10, I assume you will have to tweak your code due to deprecations and such.

You need to build with Xcode8 to archive this btw.

If you were working with `Storyboard`, I would also expect issues as `Storyboard` has been developed a lot in between.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was a little concerned about the Storyboard issue myself. Oh dear...

Comment: you will master it :-)

Comment: When I opened my project in XCode 8, the build succeeded & ran on both the simulator & device. However, I have spent nearly a week updating the design, because the iOS6 layout looked pretty messy on iOS7+. I have created several bespoke elements programmatically that will run cross version & device!

Comment: I still cannot get my head around why Apple replaced buttons in favour of text links. From a UIX perspective, text links are not as obvious, but maybe, it is time to move on from my skeuomorphic past...

Comment: What do you mean "Apple replaced buttons in favour of text links"?

Comment: For instance, in iOS6, the back button for UINavigationController navigation bar was represented by an arrow shaped button with 'back' text inside. In iOS7+, only the text 'back' is displayed. Having a button container tells the user that this is a button [if that  doesn't sound too bleeding obvious]. Sometimes, text links can get lost, although this is probably not the case for navigation bars, so I apologise for the poor example...

Answer (score 1):

> Will my MacBook Pro OSX Lion, handle the XCode 4.6.3 to Xcode 7

Absolutely not. Xcode 7 requires a *much* later system version than Lion.

In general what I have done in your situation is to install the required system and Xcode onto an external drive or a partition on the internal drive, and boot from that. This allows me to experiment and *see* whether the transition is going to work.

There is no need, therefore, to *guess* — which is what it appears you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I am thinking about getting a new MacBook Pro, anyway, because my current one is old & jaded. This maybe the way to go, or else I will do a partition.

Comment: If you _know_ you're going to get a new machine anyway, then that gives you a safe path. What I do is keep all my old machines, so if a new version of Xcode can't open an old project, I have a version that _can_ open it.

Comment: Yes. Good point. I try and keep all my old machines for a couple of years at least. This is how Apple get developers to buy new machines. Increase the memory requirements of their software & OS. Even my i5 2.9MHZ single core is feeling a little tired now. Time for a dual core...;)

Comment: It is as you say. The lack of backwards compatibility of new Xcode versions drives me crazy. Xcode 8 forced me to install El Capitan. I didn't like that! And believe me, you really don't want to run El Capitan without an SSD-based machine. OTOH you might be quite happy just installing an SSD and maxing out RAM in the machine you have now.

Comment: I have heard some pretty ominous stories about El Capitan. And surprise, surprise all the new MacBook Pros have SSD. I wonder whether Apple actually tested it on older machines?

Comment: They don't _need_ to test it on older machines because they all have new machines!